# Android Development: Keep EditText Selection Highlight On Lose Focus?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, selection, highlight

I was wondering if it's possible to keep an EditText's orange highlight around selected text when the EditText loses focus, until the user changes the selection?

I'm creating a find/replace feature in my app and say if the user selects the first 3 characters in the EditText, then decides that he/she wants to replace the selection with XXXXX and clicks on the other EditText that the user inputs what they want to replace with, the orange highlight dissappears from the original EditText, so the user can forget what he/she is going to replace, therefore I'm wondering how I can keep the orange highlight even on lose focus to prevent the confusion.

Thanks.